# guitar tab to uke tab program help

Tags: python, file

so i made this program where it take a guitar tab and gets the fret number and runs it through a dictionary which gets the note and searches for it in the uke note dictionary.

but my probleme is if i have a tab in a txt file ex:

```
|-----11----------11----------11------11--13--11----------11----------11----------11------11--13--11---------------|
|-------13----------13----------13--------------------------13----------13----------13-----------------------------|
|--13-----13---13-----13---12-----12---------------12-13------13---13-----13---12-----12--------------------------|
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

So what i would want would be to open the txt file and put a letter in front of each number corosponding with the line. so every number on the first line would have say a "e",second line:"B" and third:"G"

And have it in order so that the end result would be: G13 e11 B13 G13 etc...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the parsing, write a function that takes a line of tabs and a note, that yields the frets along with the position:

```
import re

def parse_line(line, note):
    fret_pattern = re.compile(r'\d+')
    for match in fret_pattern.finditer(line):
        yield (match.start(), ''.join((note, match.group(0))))
```

For the first line, `|-----11--`, this will yield `(6, "e11")`.  The tuples can be used later to sort all notes on all strings.

Now just `open()` the file, read in the first 6 lines and give them the correct names:

```
import itertools

notes = ['e', 'B', 'G', 'D', 'A', 'E']
with open('tab.txt') as fp:
    # Read-in 6 lines
    lines = itertools.islice(fp, 0, 6)

    # Holds all the notes.
    frets = []

    # Process the lines, append all notes to frets.
    for note, line in itertools.izip(notes, lines):
       frets.extend(parse_line(line, note))

    # Sort the frets by position.
    frets.sort()

    # Drop the positions.
    frets = [fret for pos, fret in frets]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you want. But it's late.

```
tablines  = '''|------11----------11----------11------11--13--11----------11----------11----------11------11--13--11--------------|
|-------13----------13----------13--------------------------13----------13----------13-----------------------------|
|--13-----13---13-----13---12-----12---------------12-13------13---13-----13---12-----12---------------------------|
|-----------------7------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|------9----------7------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|-----------------7------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|'''

# this will rotate them sideways, so you can compare them.
tabs = zip(*[list(l) for l in tablines.split("\n")][::-1])

ot = []
tl = len(tabs)
i = 1;
strings = 'eadgbe'
while i + 1 < tl:
    chord = []
    for j in range(6):
       # Because we need to care very strictly about order, we need to look 
       # through each point on the set of lines individually.
       dt = tabs[i][j] + tabs[i+1][j]
       if dt.isdigit():
           # both are digits, that means this is a chord.
           chord.append(strings[j] + dt)
       elif tabs[i-1][j] == '-' and tabs[i][j].isdigit():
           chord.append(strings[j] + tabs[i][j])
    if chord: # a chord has been found
       # tuples used because there the distinct possibility of two chords at once
       ot.append(tuple(chord))
    i+=1

print ot
```

The result:

> [('g13',), ('a9', 'e11'), ('b13',), ('g13',), ('g13',), ('e7', 'a7', 'd7'), ('e11',), ('b13',), ('g13',), ('g12',), ('e11',), ('b13',), ('g12',), ('e11',), ('e13',), ('e11',), ('g12',), ('g13',), ('e11',), ('b13',), ('g13',), ('g13',), ('e11',), ('b13',), ('g13',), ('g12',), ('e11',), ('b13',), ('g12',), ('e11',), ('e13',), ('e11',)]

Comment: the whole only two notes kinda ruined it for me but thanks any way

Comment: @P'sao Yea, I was tired. I fixed it now.